# How to insert an array into another array at a particular index in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm very new to perl. Need some assistance in the below scenario.

I have declared an array and trying to initialize like

```
my @array1;
$array1[0] = 1;
$array1[1] = 2;
$array1[3] = 4;
```

Now I want to insert another array lets say `my @data = [10,20,30];` at index 2 of **array1**.

So after insert **array1** should look like `[1, 2, [10,20,30],4]`

How can I do that?

Comment: Using [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) you can do this operation.

Comment: See [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) with the help of tutorial [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), backed by reference [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [array references](https://perlmaven.com/array-references-in-perl).

In short you can do

```
$array1[2] = \@data;
```

This will make the second member of `$array1` a reference to `@data`. Because this is a reference you can't access it in quite the same way as a normal array. To access `@data` via `array1` you would use `@{$array1[2]}`. To access a particular member of the reference to `@data` you can use `->` notation. See for example the simple program below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1;

$array1[0] = 1;
$array1[1] = 2;
$array1[3] = 4;
my @data = (10,20,30);
$array1[2] = \@data;

print "A @array1\n";   #Note that this does not print contents of data @data
print "B @{$array1[2]}\n"; #Prints @data via array1
print "C $array1[2]->[0]\n"; #Prints 0th element of @data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
$array1[2] = [10,20,30];
```

Be aware that what you inserting into the host array is actually an array *reference*. Hence the syntax: `[10,20,30]` is a reference while `(10,20,30)` is a list proper.

Perl doesn't have nested arrays.

Comment: What do you mean `Perl doesn't have nested array`? it's absolutely wrong, Perl supports multi-dimensional arrays well.

Comment: The way this is implemented is using array _references_. See for instance here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-multidimensional-arrays/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` for doing so.

```
use Data::Dumper;
splice @array1, 2, 0, @data;
print Dumper \@array1;
```

the `splice` prototype is:

```
splice [origin array], [index], [length of elements to replace], [replacement]
```

Comment: `splice` doesn't return the modified array. `splice` modifies the array in place and returns the removed elements (or the last removed element in scalar context).

Comment: if I don't want to create a new array instead I want to update the **array1** itself can I simply do ```splice @array1, 2, 0, @data```? Will it update?

Comment: It might be better to remove the `[]` characters, since those have meaning in Perl.  Or use some other characters.  I'm also not sure if this actually answers OP's question, since they want a nested array, and I believe this won't nest the replacement.